# Getting ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'favicon.ico'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am follwing this YT tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_j5TAhY3sw,

on 4:23:18,when he enters all the details he is able to submit ,but I get the following error:

1. ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'favicon.ico'. (On my VScode console)
2. Request Method:  POST  (On my Browser)
   Request URL:
   Django Version: 4.0.4
   Exception Type: IntegrityError
   Exception Value:
   NOT NULL constraint failed: postions_postion.invoice_id
   Exception Location: D:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 477, in execute

Its working fine using the Django admin.

This is the views.py file

```
class AddPostionsFormView(FormView):
    form_class = PositionForm
    template_name = 'invoices/detail.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.request.path
```

This is the model.py for positions:

```
from django.db import models
from invoices.models import Invoice

# Create your models here.
class Postion(models.Model):#models.Models to inherit from django.db.models.Model
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True,help_text="optional info") 
    amount=models.FloatField(help_text="in US $")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Invoice : {self.invoice.number},postion title={self.title}"
```

This is the sqlite ddb:

```
id  title   description amount  created invoice_id
1   cleaning the kitchen        30  2022-05-25 07:56:38.750572  1
2   Tarnslating test clip   100 2022-05-28 05:26:46.370414  1
3   Test    Test des    300 2022-06-01 06:53:08.567545  10
4   Good    test des    222 2022-06-01 07:08:36.972521  10
```

Update:
Stopped getting the Value Error (Favicon)

ErrorImage:

https://ibb.co/9gYQ80b

app_name = 'invoices'

This is the URLS.py:

```
#registering views in urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', InvoiceListView.as_view(), name='main'), #with class based view add as.view
    #main refers main.html
    path('new/', InvoiceFormView.as_view(), name='create'),
    #path('<pk>/', Simple_template_view.as_view(), name='simple-template'), #using pk to get the primary key of invoice to go from formsview to simple_template.html #otherwise it will go to main.html   
    path('<pk>/', AddPostionsFormView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<pk>/close/', CloseInvoiceView.as_view(), name='close'),
    path('<pk>/update/', InvoiceUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('<pk>/delete/<int:position_pk>', InvoicePostionDeleteView.as_view(), name='Delete'),
    

]
```

Comment: you supposed to share code on this page, not your entire projects code. share your views.py, problem is here: `ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'favicon.ico'. ` you are sending  string 'favicon.co', but you supposed to send a number id

Comment: I am not sending that .ico file ,I have used it only one time and just for the favicon in the entire project.

Comment: share your code where you are sending this: `ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'favicon.ico'` look closely on the error, it will say where it occur and on which line

Comment: It takes me too a base.py file that deals with queries.  Something is happening in the background. Not sure.

Comment: i bet nothing wrong with background, attach your error,  even as image, `value error` is very common mistake for beginers

Comment: I added ,I am not getting the Value error as mentioned before, but the error that was displayed on the browser.

Comment: from that error i see that you must send data in `positions_position.invoice_id` but you don't do that

Comment: Point 1 and point 2 are entirely different. The browser automatically makes a request for `favicon.ico` and your url pattern for `<pk>/` matches that request hence the error for that. You haven't shared enough code to reproduce point 2. Please see how to write a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to work with the [**`<int:…>`** path converter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) to make sure that this only matches a sequence of digits: right now it will also match all strings, including media files, so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', InvoiceListView.as_view(), name='main'), #with class based view add as.view
    #main refers main.html
    path('new/', InvoiceFormView.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('<int:pk>/', AddPostionsFormView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/close/', CloseInvoiceView.as_view(), name='close'),
    path('<int:pk>/update/', InvoiceUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete/<int:position_pk>', InvoicePostionDeleteView.as_view(), name='Delete'),
]
```

It however might be better to work with an `invoice/` prefix, or something else to prevent any confusion.